# Google Cardboard video texture on iOS with Unity 5

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I'm trying to make a spherical 360 video with the *Google Cardboard SDK*.

I have made some tests with `MovieTexture` for a desktop build that works fine, but there is no implementation of this class in iOS.

I have seen some external plugins on the asset store, but none of them seem to be compatible with *Unity 5*.

Is there a class provided by the *Cardboard SDK* to achieve this or if not do you know of another solution or plugin that can accomplish this?

Comment: I'm interested too. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I have been looking into https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/2449 . Video playback works on device and editor; but seems to fail on device as soon as I integrate the Google Cardboard camera prefab. Still looking into this, I must be making a mistake somewhere. Feel free to tell me if you have made some progress as well :)

Comment: Im having same issue,  were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally solved it.

We have to delete CardboardAppController and MMTAppController and merge them into one.

Basically in the Assets/Plugin/ios there is 2 AppControllers: "CardboardAppController.mm" (also has a CardboardAppController.h header) and "MMTAppController.mm"

The trick is that ios only "see" one app controller after generation. Since CardboardAppController comes first, MMTAppController is discarded.

**To solve this issue I have done the following:**

Create  new AppController: in my case it was named SVAppController.mm and SVAppController.h

Then we have to merge both app controller into that one and delete them.

So I copy pasted the content of CardboardAppController.h into SVAppController.h and the content of CardboardAppController.mm into SVAppController.mm (***Make sure to change the names in the code replace CardboardAppController by SVAppController***)

Then copy past the content of MMTAppController.mm into SVAppController.mm **in the right place**

And finally delete CardboardAppController and MMTAppController.

You will be left with 1 app controller and everything should be working fine.

For reference
Here is my final SVAppController:

**SVAppController.h**

```
#import "UnityAppController.h"
#import "UnityAppController+Rendering.h"
#import "UnityAppController+ViewHandling.h"

// Unity 4.6.2 added a category to the app controller.
#if UNITY_VERSION < 462
#import "UnityInterface.h"
#else
#import "UnityAppController+UnityInterface.h"
#endif

// Unity 4 used a different method name to create the UnityView.
#if UNITY_VERSION < 500
#define createUnityView initUnityViewImpl
#endif

@interface SVAppController : UnityAppController

- (void)preStartUnity;

- (UnityView *)createUnityView;

- (void)startSettingsDialog:(UIViewController *)dialog;

- (void)stopSettingsDialog;

- (void)pause:(bool)paused;

- (void)shouldAttachRenderDelegate;

@end
```

**SVAppController.mm**

```
#import "SVAppController.h"
#import "CardboardView.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
extern "C" {

    extern void readProfile();
    extern void syncProfile();

    extern "C" void MMTUnitySetGraphicsDevice(void* device, int deviceType, int eventType);
    extern "C" void MMTUnityRenderEvent(int marker);

    extern UIViewController* createSettingsDialog(id app);
    extern UIViewController* createOnboardingDialog(id app);

    bool isOpenGLAPI() {
#if UNITY_VERSION < 463
        return true;
#else
        SVAppController* app = (SVAppController *)GetAppController();
        UnityRenderingAPI api = [app renderingAPI];
        return api == apiOpenGLES2 || api == apiOpenGLES3;
#endif
    }

    void launchSettingsDialog() {
        SVAppController* app = (SVAppController *)GetAppController();
        [app startSettingsDialog:createSettingsDialog(app)];
    }

    void launchOnboardingDialog() {
        SVAppController* app = (SVAppController *)GetAppController();
        [app startSettingsDialog:createOnboardingDialog(app)];
    }

    void endSettingsDialog() {
        SVAppController* app = (SVAppController *)GetAppController();
        [app stopSettingsDialog];
    }

}  // extern "C"

@implementation SVAppController

- (void)preStartUnity {
    [super preStartUnity];
    syncProfile();
}

- (UnityView *)createUnityView {
    return [[CardboardView alloc] initFromMainScreen];
}

- (void)startSettingsDialog:(UIViewController*)dialog {
    [self pause:YES];
    [self.rootViewController presentViewController:dialog animated:NO completion:nil];
}

- (void)stopSettingsDialog {
    [[self rootViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    [self pause:NO];
}

- (void)pause:(bool)paused {
#if UNITY_VERSION < 462
    UnityPause(paused);
#else
    self.paused = paused;
#endif
}

- (void)shouldAttachRenderDelegate;
{
    UnityRegisterRenderingPlugin(&MMTUnitySetGraphicsDevice, &MMTUnityRenderEvent);
}

@end

IMPL_APP_CONTROLLER_SUBCLASS(SVAppController)
```

Comment: Nice catch, works like a charm. Do you get an OK frame rate with the plugin? My test video has kind of a slow FPS on the device.

Comment: @TiborUdvari I would say on newer devices the frame rate was decent, I get around 30. but on older devices sometimes it drops to 24 which makes it a bit clumsy. But I am ok with it overall

Comment: so I did a couple of tests on my iPhone5S, it seems fluid with a video of 480p then it starts lagging pretty hard. What size of Sphere do you  use?

Comment: Has anyone been able validate this answer? And, it works without requiring any additional Unity plug-ins?

Answer (score 2):

Movies in Unity are usually rendered as textures on objects. On mobile the issue becomes that the device only wants to display video in a video player, so the Unity class MovieTexture is not supported.

I am having success circumventing this, and successfully rendering 360-video on the inside of a sphere using a Unity plug-in from the Unity Asset Store called, Easy Movie Texture.

For working on a Mac, here's what I did:

1. Download the Easy Movie Texture plug-in from the Unity Asset Store
2. Open the Demo Sphere demo scene from Assets/EasyMovieTexture/Scene
3. Create a new (empty) Prefab to your project, and drag the Sphere GameObject from the Demo Sphere scene onto the Prefab.
4. Reopen your Cardboard scene and drag the new videosphere prefab into your hierarchy.
5. Open your source 360-video in Quicktime
6. File -> Export -> 720p
7. Change file extension from '.mov' to '.mp4'
8. Drag your new mp4 file into your projects Assets/Streaming Assets directory. Note: don't import through the menu system, as this will force Unity to convert to OGG.
9. On the "Media Player Ctrl" script component of your videosphere GameObject, locate the "Str_File_Name" field and provide the FULL filename of your newly exported video file. Make sure to include the extension as part of the string, "mymovie.mp4".

Pretty sure that's everything. Hope it helps other folks stuck on this problem.

Final note, the video will only render on the device. In the editor you will only see a white texture on the sphere. You have to publish to the device in order to see your awesome 360-video.